# Por que se detecta un query como booleano

Tags: php, booleano

soy un novato estudiante de programación y tengo un error en ciertas lineas de código, la cuestión es no se por que el query toma el valor de un booleano y me da el siguiente error.

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\index.php:74

```
<?php
                        function multi_sql($numerocategoria) {


                              $sql = " INNER JOIN categoriaevento ";
                              $sql .= " ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat ";
                              $sql .= " INNER JOIN invitados ";
                              $sql .= " ON eventos.idInv = invitados.idInvitado ";
                              $sql .= " AND eventos.id_CatEvento = $numerocategoria ";
                              $sql .= " ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2 ";

                              return $sql;
                          }

 try {
                                include_once 'includes/funciones/conexion.php';
                                $acentos = $conn -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                $sql = " SELECT idEvento, nomEvento, fechaEvento, horaEvento, CatEvento, icono, nombreInvitado,
                                apellidoInvitado FROM eventos ";
                                $sql .= multi_sql(1);
                                $sql .= multi_sql(2);
                                $sql .= multi_sql(3);
                                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                                echo $e -> getMessage();
                            }

                        ?>

                      <?php
                      echo $resultado;
                      $resultado -> fetch_assoc(); ?>
                      <?php $conn -> multi_query($sql); ?>

                      <?php do {
                          $eventos = $conn -> store_result();
                          $row = $evento -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>

                          <?php $i = 0 ?>
```

Comment: esto para que lo pones `$sql .= multi_sql(1);` ?

Comment: En la documentacion http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php te indica que mysqli puede devolverte booleanos, segun ciertas consultas. Es posible que te este dando un false (por algun error en la consulta). Te recomendaria que pusieras un `die($mysqli->error);` despues de la linea de mysqli para ver que te esta devolviendo. El Catch no te va a saltar en este caso.

Comment: ten en cuenta que `multi_sql(1)` deberia empezar por `WHERE ` para que tu consulta sea correcta, y las demas (multi_sql(2), multi_sql(3)) por algo tipo `AND` para que te construya una sql correcta. El fallo puede ir por ahi.

Comment: Imprime la variable `$sql`. Es muy probable que la misma tenga errores de sintaxis. En ese caso la llamada a `query` dará como resultado un booleano `FALSE`. Siempre conviene controlar el código en ese sentido, no escribirlo pensando que todo irá siempre como se piensa. Todos los métodos que podrían fallar convendría controlarlos con bloque `if  ... else`  o algo parecido.

Comment: Todo apunta a un error de sintaxis en la consulta sql, pero sin ver la función `multi_query()` poco más te podemos indicar acerca de la causa concreta del error.

Comment: @Xerif esta es la consulta SQL  `SELECT idEvento, nomEvento, fechaEvento, horaEvento, CatEvento, icono, nombreInvitado, apellidoInvitado FROM `eventos`; INNER JOIN categoriaevento ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat INNER JOIN invitados ON eventos.idInv = invitados.idInvitado AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 1 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2 AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 2 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2 AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 3 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `mysqli::query` solo permite ejecutar una única sentencia sql, para ejecutar multiples sentencias debemos utilizar `mysqli::multi_query`, ademas las sentencias tienen que acabar en `;` para ejecutar multiples consultas.

En tu caso, antes de decidirnos a utilizar `mysqli::multi_query` veamos que sentencia se esta esta contruyendo y revisemos si es lo mas apropiado:

Después de unir todos los trozos tenemos algo como esto

```
SELECT idEvento, nomEvento, fechaEvento, horaEvento, CatEvento, icono, nombreInvitado, apellidoInvitado FROM eventos
INNER JOIN categoriaevento ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat INNER JOIN invitados ON eventos.idInv = invitados.idInvitado AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 1 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2
INNER JOIN categoriaevento ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat INNER JOIN invitados ON eventos.idInv = invitados.idInvitado AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 2 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2
INNER JOIN categoriaevento ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat INNER JOIN invitados ON eventos.idInv = invitados.idInvitado AND eventos.id_CatEvento = 3 ORDER BY idEvento LIMIT 2
```

Obviamente esta es una consulta no válida sintácticamente, por múltiples motivos.

Deduzco que el conjunto de resultados que queremos es:
Todos los invitados junto a sus eventos y categorias, donde la categoría(id_CatEvento) de evento sea 1, 2 o 3.

Dada tu consulta podemos deducir

- que tenemos 3 tablas `eventos`, `invitados` y `categoriaevento`
- que la tabla `eventos` tiene FK `categoriaevent.idCat`
- que la tabla `invitados` tiene FK `eventos.idInv`

Si hasta aquí estoy en lo cierto, y queremos por ejemplo obtener todos los invitados que existen para todos los eventos donde la categoria sea 1, 2 o 3

Podemos hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
    /* seleccionamos los campos */
    SELECT invitados.*, eventos.*, categoriaevent.*
    /* indicamos la tabla */
    FROM invitados
    /* unimos los campos de otras tablas relacionadas*/
    INNER JOIN eventos ON invitados.idInvitado = eventos.idInv
    INNER JOIN categoriaevento ON eventos.id_CatEvento = categoriaevento.idCat
    /* establecemos las condiciones*/
    WHERE eventos.id_CatEvento = 1
       OR eventos.id_CatEvento = 2
       OR eventos.id_CatEvento = 3;
```

Fijate que solo utilizamos 2 JOIN, uno por cada tabla de la que agregamos campos, también tenemos un `WHERE` con operadores `OR` uno por cada categoria de evento que queremos de la tabla eventos.

Llegados a este punto tienes varias opciones, las mas lógicas y simples, sería descartar tu función `multi_query()` que realmente no aporta nada ya que no hay nada dinámico en la consulta y establecer la consulta directamente de forma correcta.

O modificar tu sql base y adaptar tu función `multi_query()` de forma que añada las condiciones del WHERE dinamicamente en función de tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias!!, fue un aporte de gran ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo q no uso mysqli, pero intentaste sacarle las comillas al string de consulta?

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Sii ya lo hice, aun así sigue el mismo error